# How to implement a location hierarchy upload from csv (PHP)?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, csv

I am trying to do a location based upload of data from csv. My csv upload contains (item_id, name, country, state, city, area_type, area). This will be saved in a pivot table with the following schema (item_id, location, country, state, city, area_type, area). My problem is I am not sure on how to implement this. There are a lot of things that I need to consider. First, I need to check if the listed countries, states, cities, area_type and areas are matching. Here is a sample csv

[image]

Now, what I want is to process the data on backend to check the database on their respective hierarchy. It will also eliminate all the data that is not on the list. I know there are a lot of risk on the process I want since I am using the name of the location not its id. But this is to ensure that users will be able to add data even without knowing the id from the database. And my first plan is to query the db first using where in, then I will just loop the result and that will be the data that I will dump in my db. Another thing is that I want to be able to identify if all the state, city, or areas are all selected then I will assign a value of 0 for that. Any idea how to best implement this process? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand what you are trying to do (even though your question is well-written). Can you add example data for what you have as input, what you have in your database (you probably have a list of cities/states/...), and how your input csv data should look like in your database after processing. By the way, the problem with not using ids: which of the more then 30 [cities named Paris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris_(disambiguation)) do you or the user mean when you enter the city "Paris" in your column?

Comment: @Solarflare sorry, what I am trying to achieve is so complicated, I am not even sure how to approach this problem. But to give you an example the sample image I have there is a sample csv upload. Then I have a 5 tables in my database which are connected to each other. Country table has (id, name), State table has (id, state_name, country_id), City has (id, city_name, country_id, state_id), Area type (id, area_type_name) and lastly Area table (id, area_name, country_id, state_id, city_id). These tables are interrelated to each other.

Comment: What I am currently doing is getting all the data from each table then make an associative array with their name as key and id for value. Then I am gonna loop the exploded data from csv then get the ID's based from the assoc array. Then I will query them by joining the 5 tables with a where in clause. Then the result returns the table with their corresponding hierarchy.

Comment: Then from the data I will formulate the array and save that from a pivot table with the ffg. columns (item_id, country_id, state_id, city_id, area_type_id, area_id). I was able to achieve my goal from this process but I am not confident with the flow. I feel like there are other better ways to implement this kind of logic. I hope I explained it well. Thanks

Comment: a) You should edit your question and add such information to your question (you even get a badge for this). b) Your tables in your database are wrong, you cannot (at least to do it correctly) have e.g. `City(id, city_name, country_id, state_id)`, it has to be `City(id, city_name, state_id)`, because the country is already defined by the state, same for the `area`. c) I still don't get what you are trying to do. Please add (to your question) the result that your process should create from your csv-example. I already have the problem to understand what "United States, Korea" together could mean.